# Javascript array to array of object with count

Tags: javascript

What would be the best way to convert an array of dates into an array of unique objects with a count for each date?

**Example Array**

```
['07Sep', '09Sep', '14Sep', '05Sep', '12Sep', '06Sep', '10Sep', '14Sep', '08Sep', '10Sep', '04Sep', '05Sep', '07Sep', '08Sep', '13Sep', '12Sep', '05Sep', '05Sep', '06Sep', '10Sep', '06Sep', '13Sep', '05Sep', '06Sep', '05Sep', '04Sep', '12Sep', '05Sep', '11Sep', '10Sep', '11Sep', '06Sep', '04Sep', '10Sep']
```

**Expected output with this structure:**  *(vales are made up)*

```
[
{04SEP:4},
{06SEP:2},
{07SEP:2},
{09SEP:4},
...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a single [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) statement:

```
const result = array.reduce((a, v) => ({...a, [v]: (a[v] || 0) + 1}), {});
```

In each iteration, simply [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the already accumulated result, and then increment the existing value (or 0) for each element.

---

**Snippet**:

```js
const array = ['07Sep', '09Sep', '14Sep', '05Sep', '12Sep', '06Sep', '10Sep', '14Sep', '08Sep', '10Sep', '04Sep', '05Sep', '07Sep', '08Sep', '13Sep', '12Sep', '05Sep', '05Sep', '06Sep', '10Sep', '06Sep', '13Sep', '05Sep', '06Sep', '05Sep', '04Sep', '12Sep', '05Sep', '11Sep', '10Sep', '11Sep', '06Sep', '04Sep', '10Sep'];

const result = array.reduce((a, v) => ({...a, [v]: (a[v] || 0) + 1}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. What would be the best way to also sort these values?

Comment: Do you want a single object or an array of single-key objects? Objects are usually considered to be unordered in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to group the dates and convert to your desired format using `Object.entries` and `array#map`.

```js
const input = ['07Sep', '09Sep', '14Sep', '05Sep', '12Sep', '06Sep', '10Sep', '14Sep', '08Sep', '10Sep', '04Sep', '05Sep', '07Sep', '08Sep', '13Sep', '12Sep', '05Sep', '05Sep', '06Sep', '10Sep', '06Sep', '13Sep', '05Sep', '06Sep', '05Sep', '04Sep', '12Sep', '05Sep', '11Sep', '10Sep', '11Sep', '06Sep', '04Sep', '10Sep'],
      result = input.reduce((r, date) => {
        r[date] = (r[date] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
      },{}),
      output = Object.entries(result).map(arr => Object.fromEntries([arr]));
console.log(output);
```